# Laravel JSON arrays Where Function

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

Let's say I have a table attendance with columns:

```
id, student_id, attendance, date
```

And I get a post request in JSON format like this...

```
[
    {
        "student_id": 5,
        "date": "2018-01-03",
        "attendance": 0
    }, {
        "student_id": 2,
        "date": "2018-01-03",
        "attendance": 0
    },{
        "student_id": 2,
        "date": "2018-01-03",
        "attendance": 0
    }
]
```

And die dumping the request->all() we get...

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "student_id" => 5
    "date" => "2018-01-03"
    "attendance" => 0
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "student_id" => 2
    "date" => "2018-01-03"
    "attendance" => 0
  ]
  2 => array:3 [
    "student_id" => 2
    "date" => "2018-01-03"
    "attendance" => 0
  ]
]
```

The question is how do I save or update this request in the attendance table?

I have to compare the data in the attendance table. If a row contains the student_id and date, I have to update the attendance. If the `student_id` and `date` don't exist I have to create new data.

My question: is there any function or helper to compare each of the arrays with the attendance column?

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, you've said you want to compare by `student_id` and `date` and update the existing record. Use the `updateOrCreate()` method:

```
foreach ($request->all() as $attendance) {
    Attendance::updateOrCreate($request->only('date', 'student_id'), $request->only('attendance'));
}
```

For this method, make sure the model has `$fillable` array:

```
protected $fillable = ['student_id', 'attendance', 'date'];
```

Comment: But I need to compare each of the data with attendance table as I wouldn't want to add the same data again and again if it comes. For example if request with student_id=1, date="2018-02-03", attendance="1"  data comes and my attendance table already has that data then attendace table will have two rows with same data. Hope you understand.

Comment: @AnimeshPandey how are you going to compare it? You don't have ID in the request.

Comment: I have student_id and date. I thought of comparing that with the attendane table. Is it not possible to do so?

Comment: @AnimeshPandey it's possible. I've updated the answer.